# Find the probability that there are at least three teachers in the selection.

Tags: probability, combinations

From $8$ teachers and $7$ students, $4$ people are randomly selected.

Find the probability that there are at least three teachers in the selection.

With this I knew I had to get the total of options.  So $\binom{15}{4}$.
Then I thought it would be $\binom{7}{3}$ showing the number of options $3$ teachers can be selected.
Then the number of options for a single option, so $\binom{15}{1}$, as the fourth selection could be a teacher or student.

The actual answer is $\frac{22}{65}$, just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probability follows a hyper-geometric distribution since you are picking the teachers and students from a small population with no replacement.

In general and as indicated by Wikipedia, the distribution takes the following form:

$\frac{{K \choose k} {N-K \choose n-k}}{N \choose n} $

Where:

$N$ is the population size,
$K$ is the number of success states in the population,
$n$ is the number of draws (i.e. quantity drawn in each trial),
$k$ is the number of observed successes

The probability that AT LEAST three teachers will be selected is equal to the probability that exactly three teachers will be selected + the probability that exactly four teachers will be selected so we get the following:

$\frac{\binom{8}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{1}}{\binom{15}{4}}$ for the case of exactly three teachers, the numerator gives us the number of ways we can choose the teachers in your case, we are choosing three teachers out of eight where order doesn't matter so that is $\binom{8}{3}$ and for each of these choices we need to choose one student which is why we multiply it by the total number of ways of choosing one student and that is $\binom{7}{1}$, moreover we divide this by the total number of ways we can choose any four people from what we have to get the probability  and that would be $\binom{15}{4}$

$\frac{\binom{8}{4}\cdot \binom{7}{0}}{\binom{15}{4}}$ for the case of exactly four teachers, the explanation is similar to the previous case

Then you add both together since these are mutual exclusive events.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by dividing them into cases:

**Case I**: Three teachers and one student

You can choose this in $\binom{8}{3} \times \binom {7}{1}$ ways.

So the probability for case I is given by $\frac{56 \times 7}{1365}=\frac{392}{1365}$

**Case II**: Four teachers and no student

You can choose this in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways.

So the probability for case II is $\frac{70}{1365}$

The final probability will be found by adding the two cases.